# Spring MVC - Caching static resources

Tags: caching, spring-mvc, static

If I enable static caching for all the static resources like css, js, jpg, png and gif, 
Cache-Control:public gets added to Response Headers based on the configuration.

Does it mean the resources are cached by the browser or How really does it work?

Comment: roytuts.com/cache-static-resources-like-css-js-and-images-for-a-specific-time-period/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those resources may be cached by the browser (non-shared cache) and/or by any proxy-cache (shared caches) along the way.

See this page for more details about [Cache-Control HTTP Headers](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL).